# Windows: Killing every process that stops a folder from being deleted

Tags: python, windows, directory, kill, internals

I need to delete a folder under Windows. Sometimes there are processes who prevents me from deleting said folders (their current directory is the folder, they are using one the files in the folder etc)

I'm looking for a way to loop over all processes that are using any files in my directory - then I will kill them and delete the folder.

I'm coding in Python but I guess I should be looking for some Windows Internals to do the job...

Comment: You can use Process Explorer to discover which programs have opened a file or directory, and then manually exit them gracefully. Why does this need to be automated? It seems like a questionable idea.

Comment: I'm trying to automate something, and part of it is deleting a folder that might be used by some other resources...